# LTspice simulation of LMG1210 producing unexpected results

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I want to use the LMG1210 to control a half-bridge driver circuit at 27 MHz.  I've downloaded the model and modified the file per the other posts on this website (removed the double curely brackers per the "LMG1210 application in LTspice" posting) and I do not get any syntax errors when running a transient simulation on the following design.
[image]

I do have some issues going on, though.  First, in the macroscopic sense, it looks like the voltage out of the internal LDO is drooping and pulling the enable pin down with it (4th plot pane down).  I am guessing that the internal LDO cannot source enough current through the Schottky diode at the 27 MHz operating frequency, so the 5V rail is collapsing???
[image]

So I add a dedicated 5V supply to the VCC and Enable pins as follows (circled in red):
[image]

And the waveforms it produces are shown below.  I am getting no power out to my load through the resonant LC circuit.  When I zoom in, the LO and HO signals don't look quite right.
[image]
[image]

It looks like the LO and HO are having a hard time driving the gates of the MOSFETS????
Thoughts or suggestions?

Also, I could not find a way to upload the .asc or any other file.  So let me know if the files are needed and how to attach them.

Thanks
J.

--->>> UPDATED:  Solved one problem, but found another.
Yes, the drive of the LO and HO were not sufficient for the MOSFET gates, so I added simple VCVS buffers and now the LO and HO waveforms look better in amplitide.  However, the timings of LO and HO are not making any sense.  I have set the deadtime resistors to 875 kOhm for 1 ns delays.  Here the circuit and is what I am seeing in the waveforms:
[image]
[image]

As can be seen the HO signal is going high before the LO signal is being driven low.  The HO signal is also staying on well past when LO is driven high.   Not sure what is going on.   Any ideas would be great!
J.

Comment: Solved one problem, but found another.

Comment: In the [related question you mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621426/), the accepted answer shows a method of how to post files via just copy/pasting the text inside of them.  It shows an example of both a symbol file (`.asy`) and schematic file (`.asc`).  If you want someone to troubleshoot your exact setup, you should probably include those along with the modified `.lib` file too.